# rails delayed_jobs + deleting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am trying to use delayed jobs to delete a lot of records from my db in the background but I am not sure how to completely get this done. It is not deleting the records, I am passing the user name into the `get_all_calls` but when `delayed_jobs` runs the method in 2 minutes the records do not get deleted.

What am I doing wrong that it is not working?

in my User model

```
before_destroy :destroy_calls
    def destroy_calls
      y = self.name
     self.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).get_all_calls(y)
    end

    def get_all_calls(y)
      x = Calls.where(account_name: y).limit(5000).destroy_all
       sleep(2)
    end
```

***** EDIT *****
I figured out what I Was doing wrong. I was calling `get_all_calls` wrong. This is what fixed it. But can anyone explain why I had to do `self` on my method and call it that way instead of the way I was doing it?

```
def destroy_calls
      y = self.name
     User.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).get_all_calls(y)
    end

    def self.get_all_calls(y)
      x = Calls.where(account_name: y).limit(5000).destroy_all
       sleep(2)
    end
```

Comment: can you post the full code. so we understand what is going on

Comment: this is the full code for the method that is running. did you want to see the whole model?

Comment: Is delayed_job actually running on your machine? Did you check all intermediate steps like is `destroy_calls` actually called? Is `get_all_calls` actually called?

Comment: @spickermann yes it is running. I have my logs open as I am testing this. I have logger debugs but I did not include them in the question. It hits my ```destroy_calls``` method based on the debug but when it is time for the ```get_all_calls``` method to run I do not see my debugs in log but I do see delayed_jobs running when it is time